# Merging 2 collections

Tags: c#

How to combine 2 collections in such a way that the resultant collection contains the values alternatively from both the collections

Example :-
Col A= [1,2,3,4]
Col B= [5,6,7,8]

Result Col C=[1,5,2,6,3,7,4,8]

Comment: Would the collections always be of the same length?

Comment: What is the type of the collections A and B?  Does it matter what type the result collection C has?

Comment: The data type for the collection can be any thing and the length may differ

Comment: @praveen, would the type in A *differ* from the type in B? Because that would affect the answer.

Comment: @praveen More specifically, do the collections implement `IList<T>`?  A lot of the answers below assume that they do.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram : No the type wont differ

Comment: @phoog : Not necessary . It may or may not implement Ilist<T> . I just need the resultant collection in the same data type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could do this, depending on the types of the input and the required type of the output.  There's no library method that I'm aware of, however; you'd have to "roll your own".

One possibility would be a linq-style iterator method, assuming that all we know about the input collections is that they implement `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Interleave(this IEnumerable<T> a, IEnumerable<T> b)
{
    bool bEmpty = false;
    using (var enumeratorB b.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach (var elementA in a)
        {
            yield return elementA;
            if (!bEmpty && bEnumerator.MoveNext())
                yield return bEnumerator.Current;
            else
                bEmpty = true;
        }
        if (!bEmpty)
            while (bEnumerator.MoveNext())
                yield return bEnumerator.Current;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks . Just for curiosity Can we some how implement the ZIP operator in Linq which is new to .NET 4.0 to solve the problem  ?

Comment: @praveen Anthony Pegram's answer used zip but he seems to have deleted it.  It's not the most efficient to execute, but it certainly makes the code less complicated.  The problem with it is that it truncates the longer sequence, so if you have input collections with 4 and 5 items, respectively, the output will have 8 items and you'll lose the last item in the second collection.  That may be why Anthony deleted his answer.

Comment: That is correct, I deleted the answer once the clarification was made about the sequences having unequal lengths. @praveen, if you need the code, it was simply `var list3 = list1.Zip(list2, (a, b) => new[] { a, b }).SelectMany(x => x);`. But again, this leaves out elements of whichever sequence is longer.

Answer (score 2):

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
int[] b = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] result = a.SelectMany((n, index) => new[] { n, b[index] }).ToArray();
```

If collection a and b haven't the same length, you need to be careful to use `b[index]`, maybe you need : `index >= b.Length ? 0 : b[index]`

Answer (score 2):

If the collections do not necessarily have the same length, consider an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AlternateMerge<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                               IEnumerable<T> other)
{
    using(var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    using(var otherEnumerator = other.GetEnumerator())
    {
        bool haveItemsSource = true;
        bool haveItemsOther = true;
        while (haveItemsSource || haveItemsOther)
        {
            haveItemsSource = sourceEnumerator.MoveNext();
            haveItemsOther = otherEnumerator.MoveNext();

            if (haveItemsSource)
                yield return sourceEnumerator.Current;

            if (haveItemsOther)
                yield return otherEnumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

And use :

```
List<int> A = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> B = new List<int> { 5, 6, 7, 8 };

var mergedList = A.AlternateMerge(B).ToList();
```

Comment: Many enumerators will throw an exception if you call MoveNext after receiving a false return value.  This answer doesn't protect against that.

Comment: That's not what the docs say, and I didn't see that at least for regular collections (worked just fine) - got an example for that behavior? (docs say **When the enumerator is at this position, subsequent calls to MoveNext also return false until Reset is called.**)

Comment: No, now that I've posted that, I can't find any supporting evidence.  I am sure I've seen it before.  Perhaps it was proprietary code that had been written by someone who didn't read the docs.

Comment: Reset is known to throw, it's essentially recommended to be non-supported. MoveNext, on the other hand, I wouldn't know of an implementation that does that. Not that I write any production code explicitly using enumerators.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that both collections are of equal length:

```
Debug.Assert(a.Count == b.Count);

for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
{
   c.Add(a[i]);
   c.Add(b[i]);
}

Debug.Assert(c.Count == (a.Count + b.Count));
```

Answer (score -2):

Use Linq's Union extension such as:

```
var colA = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var colB = new List<int> { 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8};

var result = colA.Union( colB); // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

Comment: "contains the values alternatively", so index 0 from A remains, index 0 from B is 1 in the new array, etc.